# Coldfusion variable to code

Tags: variables, coldfusion, code-generation

I need a way to turn code stored in a variable into real code. We are passing Video embed code inputed from a form through to a page to display the video. Its so that people can 'attach' a shared video from another site to a post.

```
<cfoutput>
    #attributes.embed#
</cfoutput>
```

simply outputs the code as text

Comment: When you 'view source' on the page, do you see angle brackets around the pasted code or sanitized code &gt; &lt;?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer if anyone else is looking:
http://speeves.erikin.com/2009/06/coldfusion-replace-html-ized-characters.html

Answer (score 1):

This could open up a security hole depending on what people paste in here. Is it possible to ask visitors to paste in the URL of the shared video and depending on the format of the URL you output it into your own code? Using a switch statement based on the inputted URL, you could provide one output template for YouTube, another for Vimeo, etc.

EDIT

That said, HTML code should output easily unless it has been escaped. However, if you wish to output Coldfusion code, you will need to write the code to a file and then cfinclude the file into your output document. (not recommended, but possible)

EDIT 2

When you 'view source' on the page, do you see angle brackets around the pasted code or angle brackets replaced with &rt and &gt? if you see the &gt then something along the way has encoded the HTML, and you'll need to decode it again with a function around the variable.

```
<cfoutput>
#decodeFunctionHere(attributes.embed)#
</cfoutput>
```

Coldfusion 8 has a decode function named [urlDecode](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_t-z_09.html) if your text is encoded to a url format, using % signs. For &gt &rt another function will need to be used to do the substitution. Should be one on cflib.org or it's easy to write. Let me know.

Comment: We want it from any source whatsoever. We will be using regex to pull the relevant bits of info from the code inserted though. But I wanted to know how to do the above anyway.

Comment: So Like i said, I think your code above is enough to display any HTML unless it has been sanitized along the way. Coldfusion code is the only script that should require the extra save it to disk first step. (unless they've introduced a new way of doing that in most recent versions)

Comment: you would only need to write it to a file and include it if its CFML code that he wants to execute.  If its simply HTML embed code for a video, he can simply save it in a variable and output it.

Comment: the below answer was the one I was looking for.